# Android background gradient radial

Tags: android, xml, drawable, gradient, radial

I want that my app have a background gradient radial, and i Think I did it, but in runtime my app show just one color.

Here my drawable background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:type="radial"
    android:gradientRadius="360"
    android:startColor="@color/color_start"
    android:endColor="@color/color_end" />
```

And I call it in my activity XML in this way:

```
android:background="@drawable/background_app"
```

PD:Sorry about my bad English

Comment: What are the values you store in the `color_start` and `color_end`, because this code works fine for me.

Comment: <color name="color_end">#001e2e</color>
 <color name="color_start">#fff</color> My app only show white @BartoszLipinski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android:gradientRadius="250" will be ignored. You should point to a dimen resource with a px or dp value, like: android:gradientRadius="@dimen/gradient_radius"

Comment: 1+ for you really helped